# How to use default identify tool in ArcMap from C#?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, c#, identify

I made a custom "Find" tool (winform) which is called after specific button pressed in an ArcMap toolbar. In this new "Find" form I need to use identify for one or more selected items in DataGridRow. So far I failed to find a way to call default "Identify" tool from ArcMap. I could make my own tool, but that seams like a waste of time, as I don't need any custom functionality in it.

Is there a way to call ArcMap "Identify" form (with feature properties etc.) from my custom winform tool passing one or more features?

I'm relatevly new to ArcMap as well as C#.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the below snippet from [ESRI Website](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000n0000000)

```
public void FindCommandAndExecute(ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication application, System.String commandName)
{
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = application.Document.CommandBars;
  ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID uid = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
  uid.Value = commandName; // Example: "esriFramework.HelpContentsCommand" or "{D74B2F25-AC90-11D2-87F8-0000F8751720}"
  ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(uid, false, false);

  if (commandItem != null)
    commandItem.Execute();
}
```

The identify tool's UID in 9.3 is   `{CF605583-AEA3-41D8-9464-DDD1905243D9}` or `esriControls.ControlsMapIdentifyTool`

I am not sure if it is same in version 10

**Edit**

I believe you are trying to pop up a custom attribute form with the attributes of the user selected feature.
I am assuming a case where where the "STREET_NAME" field value needs to get populated in a textbox. For this,

Find the ObjectId of the selected feature. Refer IFeatureSelection, IFeatureCursor etc..
//get the field values

```
IFeature pFeature = featureClass.GetFeature(objectid);
string streetName = pFeature.Value(pFeature.Fields.FindField("STREET_NAME"));
txtStreetName.Text = streetName;
```

If you are looking at creating dynamic userforms, you will need to loop all fields and field values.

Comment: It activates "Identify" command the same way as clicking on button, but so far it seams that i cant really use it in my situation, because I need it to open "identify" form(like normaly you would click on identify command, and then on desired feature/s and it opens the form showing theyr properties). My apollagies, the question might have not been exactly correct. Slightly edited question!

Comment: From your given link i found something very similar to what I need - [link.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Do_Identify_Snippet/00490000000n000000/) Unfortunatelly its not exactly what i wanned to get. From that sample I managed to get [this(wrong)](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/8120/wrongd.jpg), but i waned to get [this(correct)](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8460/correcty.jpg)